# how to insert enum column type in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums

I have problem when i want insert data and have enumtype column in mysql. but my sql always rollback my create. my question is how to insert datase with enum type in column mysql
here my code when i want create

```java
System.out.print(" ExecTransType "+message.getString(ExecTransType.FIELD));
String Orders = message.getString(OrdType.FIELD);
if (Orders.equals("P")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrdType("PEGGED");
}else if (Orders.equals("1")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrdType("MARKETORDER");
} else if (Orders.equals("2")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrdType("LIMIT");
}
System.out.print(" OrdType "+message.getString(OrdType.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setExecType(message.getString(ExecType.FIELD));
System.out.print(" ExecType "+message.getString(ExecType.FIELD));
String status = message.getString(OrdStatus.FIELD);
if (status.equals("0")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrderStatus("NEW");
}else if(status.equals("1")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrderStatus("PARTIALFILLED");
}else if(status.equals("2")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrderStatus("FILLED");
}else if(status.equals("3")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrderStatus("DONEFORDAY");
}else if(status.equals("4")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrderStatus("CANCELLED");
}else if(status.equals("8")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrderStatus("REJECTED");
}else if(status.equals("C")){
    newordersingleObj.setOrderStatus("EXPIRED");
}

System.out.print(" OrdStatus "+message.getString(OrdStatus.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setSide(message.getInt(Side.FIELD));
System.out.print(" Side "+message.getInt(Side.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setOrderQty(message.getDouble(OrderQty.FIELD));
System.out.print(" OrderQty "+message.getDouble(OrderQty.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setLeavesQty(message.getDouble(LeavesQty.FIELD));
System.out.print(" LeavesQty "+message.getDouble(LeavesQty.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setCumQty(message.getDouble(CumQty.FIELD));
System.out.print(" CumQty "+message.getDouble(CumQty.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setLastShares(message.getDouble(LastShares.FIELD));
System.out.print(" LastQty "+message.getDouble(LastShares.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setAveragePrice(message.getDouble(AvgPx.FIELD));
//                newordersingleObj.setCheckSum("95");
newordersingleObj.setPrice(message.getDouble(Price.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setCurrency(message.getString(Currency.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setMsgSeqNum(3);
newordersingleObj.setSenderCompId("Fastmatch1");
newordersingleObj.setTargetCompID("TRValueTrade2UAT1");
newordersingleObj.setSendingTime(message.getString(TransactTime.FIELD));
newordersingleObj.setCreated_at(time);
System.out.print("sebelum insert ke db");
RepositoryFactory.getOrderRepository().create(newordersingleObj);
```

here my enum class

```
public enum enumOrderStatus {
    NEW, PARTIALFILLED, FILLED, DONEFORDAY, CANCELLED, REJECTED, EXPIRED
}
```

and here my second enum class

```
public enum enumOrderType {
    PEGGED, LIMIT, MARKETORDER
}
```

and here my entity for enum type why cannot convert enum type in mysql

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name="OrderStatus")
        private enumOrderStatus OrderStatus;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name="OrdType")
        private enumOrderType OrdType;
public String getOrderStatus() {
            return this.OrderStatus.name();
        }

        public void setOrderStatus(enumOrderStatus OrderStatus) {
            this.OrderStatus = OrderStatus;
        }

        public String getOrdType() {
            return this.OrdType.name();
        }

        public void setOrdType(enumOrderType OrdType) {
            this.OrdType = OrdType;
        }
```

```
there is no error 
but my code like stack in this 

    Hibernate: insert into new_single_order_response (AveragePrice, ClOrdID, created_at, CumQty, Currency, ExecID, ExecTransType, ExecType, LastShares, LeavesQty, MsgSeqNum, OrdType, OrderID, OrderQty, Price, SenderCompId, SendingTime, Side, Symbol, TargetCompID, TransactTime, updated_at, OrderStatus) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 

i also have catch error but there is no error only stack for insert to my database


        } catch (FieldNotFound e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

my question is how to insert to enum column using java ? because i got error when i want create there is always roll back my execution so i cannot insert to my database. and my data cannot insert to my database always rollback but there is no error capture here
```

Comment: And what is the exception you get?

Comment: Hibernate: insert into new_single_order_response (AveragePrice, ClOrdID, created_at, CumQty, Currency, ExecID, ExecTransType, ExecType, LastShares, LeavesQty, MsgSeqNum, OrdType, OrderID, OrderQty, Price, SenderCompId, SendingTime, Side, Symbol, TargetCompID, TransactTime, updated_at, OrderStatus) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
only get that and my data not create in my database

Comment: catch (FieldNotFound e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
i have set catch but i didnot get an error but my data cannot insert to my database

Comment: Please don't add additional information as comments, those are unreadable. Instead edit your question.

Comment: Please read this article https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i have try using that code but i got same error